# Python: Store Token in Memory

Tags: python, variables, memory, store

I have a class and in that class I have a function that performs authentication and returns a token.

I would like to store that token in memory for use by other functions in that same class.

How would I do so ?

Comment: _Show code_ to get more useful answers.

Comment: It's questions like these that give me that warm-and-fuzzy feeling towards the StackOverflow community: people willing to learn, and people politely teaching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming a structure like this:

```
class myClass(object):
  def doAuth(self):
    callAuthProcedure()
```

if `callAuthProcedure` returns the token, simply adjust it to do this:

```
class myClass(object):
  def doAuth(self):
    self.token = callAuthProcedure()
```

Later, other methods on the instance of the class can use `self.token` as necessary.